# mod_rewrite to proxy multiple servers

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm running CentOS on 3 servers.  Server A runs my apache web server.  Server B and C run other servers on different ports.  I'm trying to get htt://serverA/math/ to proxy to htt://serverB:8765/ but I'm getting errors I can't seem to fix.  Here is my entry into the httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^math/(.*)$ http://serverB:8765/$1 [P]
```

I get the following error in my log:

```
[error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/html/math
```

If I change the httpd.conf to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://serverB:8765/$1 [P]
```

All traffic to server A is redirected properly to server B, so I know that mod_rewrite and mod_proxy are working.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: the p's were removed from the http's in order to post fewer than one hyperlink, per severfaults policy

Answer (score 2):

I think your rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^/math/(.*)$ http://serverB:8765/$1 [P]
```

Since it's not matched, you get the error messages

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to proxy properly.  The page loads, but all of the images are lost and and links point to the wrong place.

Comment: If images have absolute path (like /images/something.png), you will get problems because it will try to load image on ServerA. you have to use relative path or add /math/ in absolute path.

Comment: The best practice would be to do RewriteRule ^/math/(.*)$ http://serverB:8765/math/$1 [P] and put everything in /math/ on serverB, so that links will work in every case. When connecting through serverA and when reaching directly serverB

Comment: The site running on ServerB I have very little control over other than port, and it does seem to be using absolute paths.  Are thare any other ways to deal with this?

Comment: What kind of url are not loading ? do you have logs on ServerA ?

Answer (score 0):

katriel is right but you could also use the ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse directive. See [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass). It's design to do what you want in a much simple way.
Example:

```
ProxyPass /math/ http://serverB:8765/
ProxyPassReverse /math/ http://serverB:8765/
```

Comment: This gives me the same problem as his.

Answer (score 0):

radius is right--you're better off using the actual proxy directives. Something like this should work:

```
<Location /math>
    ProxyPass http://serverB:8765/
    ProxyPassReverse http://serverB:8765/
</Location>
```

The error that you're getting may be because you're proxying ".../math/" but not ".../math".